# Question about getting asyncmongo query result in Tornado web

Tags: python, mongodb, tornado

Hi 
    I know this is a common issue for user who is not familiar with async method....
     i want to query db with user id using asyncmongo to check if the user log on, but obviously this doesn't work and i don't want to use self.render in call back.

Thanks for your help.

class MainPage(BaseHandler):

```
def get(self):

    if not self.current_user:
     ####  get no result here 
    .............
```

get_current_user function using asyncmongo method:

```
def get_current_user(self):
    user_id = self.get_secure_cookie("user")
    if not user_id: return None 
    self.db.users.find({'user_id': bson.ObjectId(str(user_id))}, limit=1, callback=self._on_response)

def _on_response(self, response, error):
    if error:
        raise tornado.web.HTTPError(500)
    how to return the value of response instead of self.render('template',response) ?
```

Answer (score 2):

see [Tornado Asynchronous Handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938902/tornado-asynchronous-handler/4939170#4939170)

Comment: Thanks, i will use sync method to get the value.

Answer (score -3):

```
def _on_response(self, response, error):
    if error:
        raise tornado.web.HTTPError(500)
    self.render(str(response))
```