# Thrift + Tornado + Async

Tags: asynchronous, thrift, tornado

Is there any way to asynchronously pass Thrift protocol through Tornado web server?

Comment: Can I implement an analog "pyamf + Django" - "thrift + tornado". While maintaining a async work?

Answer (score 2):

```
twisted:         Generate Twisted-friendly RPC services.
tornado:         Generate code for use with Tornado.
```

The command is `thrift -gen py:tornado -out ./ hello.thrift`

Answer (score 0):

Async indeed includes two parts: tornado async response to reqeust, function aysnc communitation with thrift server.

1. Tornado supports aysnc response. You can refer to [Tornado Async HTTP returning results incrementally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11900634/tornado-async-http-returning-results-incrementally) and [Tornado Asynchronous Handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938902/tornado-asynchronous-handler)
2. thrift aysnc communication. You can refer to https://chamibuddhika.wordpress.com/2011/10/02/apache-thrift-quickstart-tutorial/, although using Java, i think it'll helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to call a blocking function from a coroutine is to use a ThreadPoolExecutor, which returns Futures that are compatible with coroutines:

```
thread_pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(4)

@gen.coroutine
def call_blocking():
    yield thread_pool.submit(blocking_func, args)
```

the blocking_func may your thrift function.